# Cannot get filename from AjaxFileUpload using javascript and asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I've tried solving this out and researching for weeks and i still can't get it to work. My code is to simply upload images and then save it in the database without postback.

As of now, I used AjaxFileUpload to upload images. My plan was to get the uploaded filename in AjaxFileUpload using javascript and then store it in a hiddenfield. And then when the admin clicks submit, it will get the value that was stored in the hiddenfield and then save it in the database(using the query that i have created in my code-behind).

The problem is, it will always return empty. I hope you guys can really help me on this one.

Here is the code for the aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
CodeFile="CreateBrands.aspx.cs" Inherits="Pages_CreateBrands" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" 
TagPrefix="asp"%>  

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Music Store</title>
<script src="../Javascript/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Styles/jquery.bxslider.css"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="~/Images/rockSign.png"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function abc() {
    var elem1 = document.getElementById('<%# itemFileUpload1.ID %>').value;
        document.getElementById('HiddenInput1') = elem1;
    var elem2 = document.getElementById('<%# itemFileUpload2.ID %>').value;
        document.getElementById('HiddenInput2') = elem2;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
                    </asp:ScriptManager>
     <div id="wrapper">

         <h1>Item Image1:</h2>
         <br />

         <asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="itemFileUpload1" runat="server"
         Width="300px" OnUploadComplete="itemUploadImage1"
         OnClientUploadComplete="abc"/>
       <input type="hidden" id="HiddenInput1" name="HiddenInput" value="" />

        <h1>Item Image2:</h2>
        <br />

        <asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="itemFileUpload2" runat="server" 
         Width="300px" OnUploadComplete="itemUploadImage2" 
        OnClientUploadComplete="abc"/>
       <input type="hidden" id="HiddenInput2" name="HiddenInput" value="" />
        <br/>

      <asp:Label ID="lblResult2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        <br />

      <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="submitButton" 
      Text="Save Item" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>

    </div>
   </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

And here is the code for the aspx.cs:

```
  protected void itemUploadImage1(object sender, AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{

        string filename = Path.GetFileName(e.FileName);
        itemFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Brands/String Instrument Items/Guitar/") + filename);
}

protected void itemUploadImage2(object sender, AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(e.FileName);
        itemFileUpload2.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Brands/String Instrument Items/Guitar/") + filename);

}

 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        try {

            string item_image1 = Request.Form["HiddenInput1"];
            string item_image2 = Request.Form["HiddenInput2"];

            ConnectionClassGuitarItems.AddStringInstrumentItems(item_image1,item_image2);

            lblResult2.Text = "Upload successful!" + item_image1 + " and " + item_image2;

            ClearTextFields2();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblResult2.Text = ex.Message;
        }
}
```

Notice the the Button1_Click, I try to access the value of HiddenInput1 and HiddenInput2 but it seems like they are empty.

Comment: Are you trying to get the name of the file on the cllient's machine?

Comment: @litelite - yes, because i've tried retrieving the file in code-behind and it did not work. That's why i thought, maybe if i somehow retrieve the filename on clients side, maybe it'll work. But it turns out that it is not working also. As of now, I ran out of ideas on how to achieve this.

Comment: @mjwills - i was able to know if its empty through gridview. the image columns for image1 and 2 is empty.

Comment: @mjwills - same results even with different browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a regular asp:FileUpload control and wrap part of your form/code block in an updatepanel to achieve the same desired action as using a AjaxFileUpload control:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Always" ID="updPnlName">
 <ContentTemplate>
   <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="fileImport" CssClass="form-control"/>
 </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code Behind:

```
    protected void btnUpload_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (fileImport.HasFile)
        {
            UploadProcessFile();
        }
    }

    private void UploadProcessFile()
    {            
        var fileName = fileImport.FileName;
        //Process the rest of your code below you can also assign the file name to your textbox.
    }
```

Comment: Interesting! This actually worked for me. But there's a missing <ContentTemplate> tho after UpdatePanel.

Comment: I haven't thought of this approach before. I have already tried updatepanel previously and it will still always refresh the page when i'm uploading images. Your approach have removed it the refresh.

Comment: Sorry about the missing <ContentTemplate>.  Glad I can be of assistance, even though sometimes updatepanels can be evil, in this case they always seem to work, I have since added it to the original response.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your image name like this on aspx file on

```
 <asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="itemFileUpload2" runat="server" 
     Width="300px" OnUploadComplete="itemUploadImage2" 
    OnClientUploadComplete="abc"/>
```

use this script

```
    function abc(sender, args) {
           var Imagename = args.get_fileName();
         alert(Imagename );
       }
```

this way is very simple hope this help you